# How to uninstall windows after I’ve already dual booted it with Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, delete

So I’ve become fairly used to Ubuntu and plan to make it my main OS. In fact it’s already my main OS I never use windows anymore and I have nothing important saved on my windows OS so how would I go about uninstalling it after I’ve already dual booted it with windows?

Comment: Are you able to update UEFI either from Linux (only some new systems) or directly from a FAT32 partition with update file. Many systems only have an .exe which you cannot easily extract & update from Linux.  May be best just to keep Windows in a small NTFS partition with some extra space as it needs that to run well.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly common in Linux to want a "clean system," so I got used to rebuilding my system as a practice.  If you store your personal files on a separate drive from the OS this is actually quite simple.

Just rebuild your system without the dual boot capacity (i.e. rebuild with Ubuntu and forget about Windows).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start your Ubuntu.  Get a print out of your partition scheme.

Then make a bootable USB or CD of Gparted Live.

Delete the Windows partition. Expand Ubuntu to fill the space. Don't forget to hit Apply!

Then make a bootable USB drive of Boot Repair and run it.  You may not have to do this but be prepared.

Done
[image]